# Why is my initialization_action script on Dataproc failing to set environment variables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to set an environment variable containing the bucket of the Dataproc cluster. Basically, I add those lines to my initialization action script:

```
BUCKET=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-bucket)

cat << 'EOF' >> ~/.bashrc
export BUCKET=${BUCKET}
EOF

source /root/.bashrc
```

However, when I ssh into master to check if this line got added to the bashrc file, I can't find anything. Would you please tell me what I'm doing wrong or how would you go about this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After many trials, I first notice, I was manipulating different paths, i.e. `$HOME` and `/root/`. And then the `.bashrc` file is present under both paths, final code snippet looks like:

```
BUCKET=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-bucket)
echo "export BUCKET=${BUCKET}" | tee -a $HOME/.bashrc

source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Don't hesitate if you have any other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization actions run as `root`.  You could update `/etc/profile`.

```
MY_VAR="hello"
echo "export MY_VAR=${MY_VAR}" | tee -a /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update bucket variable in the following manner:

```
BUCKET=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-bucket)
echo "export BUCKET=${BUCKET}" | tee -a /etc/*bashrc
```

However, in order to use spark on the cluster I had to update spark config files as well:

```
BUCKET=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-bucket)
echo "export BUCKET=${BUCKET}" | tee -a /etc/profile.d/spark_config.sh /etc/*bashrc /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
```